# Connecting To Analysis Services Tabular Model

Tags: c#, impersonation, ssas-tabular

I have a .NET 6 application that's trying to connect to an Analysis Services Tabular model stored on an Analysis server.  I'm using this code to connect.  (I replace the dashes with the correct Analysis server name before running).

```
        using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var serverName = "------------";
            using var server = new Server();                        
            server.Connect($"Provider=MSOLAP; Data Source={serverName};");
        }
```

But the connection attempt fails with the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'

How do I resolve this error?  Do I have to add something to my connection string to set the impersonation mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core, and are cross-platform.

To connect from .NET 5 or later use the [ADOMD.NET for .NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.NetCore.retail.amd64) or [AMO for .NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.NetCore.retail.amd64).

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get past this error in my .NET 6 app.  I also got the same error in a .NET 5 app.  But it works using .NET Framework 4.7.2.  This is fine for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the wrong NuGet package. The one you want is `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.NetCore.retail.amd64`. No, really.